# How can I stub, or wrap, or reassign C functions during testing of a file in the same unit?

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded

> Compiler: GCC 7.4 (C compiler)
>
> Unit test framework: Cantata 6.2

I have a unit in test in which functions take this general form:

```c
void functionName(type *x, type y, type *result)
{
   assert(NULL != result);
   *result = OK;

   if (NULL == x)
      *result = NOT_OK;

   if (OK == *result)
      otherFunction(y, result);

   if (OK == *result)
      anotherFunction(y, result);

   if (OK == *result)
      yetAnotherFunction(y, result);
}
```

All the inputs to all the functions in the unit, and a number of unit-level variables, are tested in various ways as a matter of course. I now have a test coverage problem, because I am unable to stub functions *within the same unit* which are called by the function under test, and, therefore, I cannot force the `result` of the called function. This means that some of those `(OK == *result)` predicates can never be false.

How do you get around this?

I have tried reassigning the inner function in the test script:

```
anotherFunction = stubFunction;
```

This, not entirely unpredictably, gives me this compilation error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: It seems as if you can use function pointers if I understand correctly.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly. Do you want `anotherFunction` equal to `stubFunction` in the scope of `functionName`? I think you can only have that by redeclaring:

`void (*anotherFunction)(type, type*) = stubFunction;`

Comment: Canata can create BEFORE, REPLACE, AFTER wrappers for functions and will instrument your code accordingly, even for functions within the SUT itself.